# Configuration does not have any version information - assuming the configuration is for version 1.5

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Where in ccnet.config set version? I search and read docs but there is no version mentioned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add this line in your config file:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" xmlns="http://thoughtworks.org/ccnet/1/5">
```

It is mentionned in this tracker CCNET-1870 :
http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1870

Answer (score 3):

@Andy I got the same error in one of my configurations.
If you use cb:include in your configuration file, you should also give xmlns=version-url cb:config-template in configuration files included by cb:include.